# I getting the error when working with Image in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-nova

This is code in User Nova model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3UN9.png)

This is the field in users table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QRVW.png)

And when I come to Nova see this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHtus.png)

With what it can be connected? And how to solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need to run `php artisan storage:link`. Please post code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: I did it. Did not help

Comment: @ceejayoz it helped for File::make()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: App\Nova\User, fields() method: 
Image::make('Avatar', 'image')->maxWidth(50),

In Nova admin pannel User table has error in Avatar field: "The image could not be loaded". Check pictures